# regExp matching using older JAVA API

Tags: java, regex, string

I m trying to replace " with \" in my string. I am using

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\\"").matcher(myString).replaceAll("\\\\\"")
```

It works fine with my development machine as I m using newer version of JAVA. On the test machine it throws NoClassDefFounError .The test machine which closely resemble the production environment has an older version of JAVA. I am not sure which version it is.

I also tried with,

```
myString.replaceAll("\\\"","\\\\\"");
```

It throws NoSuchMethod Exception.
Also it is same problem with

```
myString.matches()
```

Can someone help me out with the ways to work with regular expression in older JAVA versions?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is possible that the environment is older than Java 1.4, when [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package is first introduced.

Comment: Yes.It is definitely older than that

Comment: Of course, you should use the productive JVM also for development, as you will run into these things lots of times. There had been many API additions in 1.4...

Comment: You should push them to update to a newer environment. Java 1.4 is more than 10 years ago already and if the environment is even older than that, it is way outdated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29

Comment: I will try to advice them. But I wonder how java developers were dealing with regular expression back then. Any resources relating to that?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Still an interesting question. In some ME environments, this might still be relevant

Comment: There is this library for Java ME: http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/ . This claims to run on any version, but I am not sure - take a look: http://jregex.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: I would not take an old regex library from then. In fact only after 1.4 regex became such a pervasive success in Java. Mind also the non-regex `replace("\"", "\\\"")` is from later date. So you have to code (=think). So sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the symptoms in the question, it is likely that you are running on a JVM that is **older** than version 1.4, which is when [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package is introduced. I think you could try to push them to upgrade the system, since version 1.4 is [first released 11 years ago in 2002](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29).

For now, you can work around with `String.indexOf` and [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)<sup>1</sup>. This is not very pretty, but sufficient for fixed string searching and replacement<sup>2</sup>.

If you insist on regex, [JRegex library](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/index.html) is worth trying. The site claims that it works on any version of Java, and the regex features that it supports is quite rich.

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup> [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is only available from Java 1.5

<sup>2</sup> [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which replace a fixed string with another fixed string, is only available from Java 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Here, answering my own question.

Implemented following simple code to effectively escape double quotes (i.e to replace " with \") and also ignores the quotes that are already escaped.

```
int index = myString.indexOf('"');

while(index != -1){     
    if(index == 0 || myString.charAt(index-1) != '\\'){
        myString= myString.substring(0,index)+"\\\""+myString.substring(index+1);  //Escaping the double quote if any in the string
        index = myString.indexOf('"', index+2);
    }
    else{
        index = myString.indexOf('"', index+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Java 1.3 doesn't have String.replaceAll?  Can we write our own?

```
public class StringReplaceAll {

    public static String replaceAll(String text, String find, String replace) {
        if (text == null || find == null || replace == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (find.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int start = 0;
        int end = text.indexOf(find, start);
        if (end == -1) {
            return text;
        }
        int findLen = find.length();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text.length());
        while (end != -1) {
            sb.append(text.substring(start, end));
            sb.append(replace);
            start = end + findLen;
            end = text.indexOf(find, start);
        }
        sb.append(text.substring(start));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void assertEquals(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
            throw new RuntimeException();
        if (!s1.equals(s2))
            throw new RuntimeException("<" + s1 + ">!=<" + s2 + ">");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertEquals("lazy fox jumps lazy dog",
                replaceAll("quick fox jumps quick dog",
                        "quick",
                        "lazy"));

        assertEquals("quick fax jumps quick dag",
                replaceAll("quick fox jumps quick dog", "o", "a"));

        assertEquals("",
                replaceAll("quick fox jumps quick dog",
                        "quick fox jumps quick dog",
                        ""));

        assertEquals("quick fox jumps quick dog",
                replaceAll("quick fox jumps quick dog", "zzz", "xxx"));

        assertEquals("quick fox jumps quick cat",
                replaceAll("quick fox jumps quick dog", "dog", "cat"));

        assertEquals("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
                replaceAll("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "a", "z"));

        assertEquals("zzzz", replaceAll("aa", "a", "zz"));

        assertEquals("", replaceAll("", "a", "z"));

        try {
            replaceAll(null, "a", "z");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

        try {
            replaceAll("a", "z", null);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

        try {
            replaceAll("a", null, "z");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

        try {
            replaceAll("a", "", "z");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        }
    }
}
```